# Does ET.parse automatically open and close a XML file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree, raspberry-pi3

I am using ET.parse(path) to parse a xml file and read from it. 
Does ET.parse auto closes the xml file after opening ? 
Is it a safe way to access the file for reading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fdfca5f0ffa831a3365cbabf9ed8fd05e9c4da49/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L574)

Unless the `source` argument is a readable stream (has a `.read()` method), it is treated as a file path. The file will be opened and [closed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fdfca5f0ffa831a3365cbabf9ed8fd05e9c4da49/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#L609) after parsing.

If you pass a stream, the stream will remain open.

Comment: Yes my source argument is the path to a xml file(abc.xml)

Answer (score -1):

It is the best way to open a XML file. It just gets everything that is in the file so no opening or closing.